# getMapAsync crashes device

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I always used to use `mapView.getMap()`, until this got deprecated. Since then I've attempted to switch over to using the following:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            if (googleMap != null) {
```

Quite a bit longer, and seems to do about the same. The only problem is, this crashes my app while removing the map. The map gets removed by calling `removeAllViews();` on one of it's parents, multiple parents up.

The map is contained in a singleton.

```
public static MapDetailsPane getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (MapDetailsPane.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MapDetailsPane();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

private MapDetailsPane() {
    mapView = new MapView(context);
```

Therefore the `mapView` is reused.

The crashing can have two different outcomes, either the app just crashes and gives no report, or the device completely restarts. My current testing device is running Android 5.0.2, I do not have any other devices (easily) available to me for testing.

What could be the cause of the problem? And how could I go about solving this? As the device completely restarts debugging has been terribly hard so far.

Comment: `MainActivity.getInstance()` <= looks scarry (may point to no longer valid Activity) `DataManager.getInstance().getContext()` <= even more scarry (may point to no longer valid context may also point to not valid context - like Application's context - which is not valid for views)   ... also **where is logcat's log**

Comment: Code might be bad, but I don't think that question itself should be down voted.

Comment: @Selvin you might not get LogCat log if your device restarts.

Comment: @Selvin this code is indeed crap, as it's in a scetch project meant purely for testing this bug. As for the logcat, that's proven terribly unreliable, as the point of crashing varies greatly. So far I've only been able to pin it down to "somewhere after `parent.removeAllViews()` ".

Comment: use comand line "adb logcat" to file "adb logcat >mylogs.txt" (as android studio clears logcat output after disconect) maybe it will catch more logs

Comment: ... also why you wana use `parent.removeAllViews` ... to reuse `MapView` you should call all needed lifecycle methods like: `onPause`, `onResume`, etc....

Comment: @Selvin calling all those methods makes no difference for this specific problem.
Also, indeed using `adb logcat>logs.txt` is quite a bit more reliable than using Android Studio, but still I can't narrow down when the problem occurs. It seems to occur when my layout gets redrawn, but I've got no idea as to how to debug that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After (a huge amount of) debugging using logcat, I finally found the problem. One of the parents of the mapview gets it's width set to 0. Apparently the mapview doesn't like this, and decides it's time to restart the tablet. Because of `mapview.getMap()` not being asynchronous I never ran into this before.